# Converting 2012-12-19 string to datetime object in Python

Tags: python

I have the following working code:

```
import datetime

d = "2012-12-19"                
f = map(int,  d.split('-') )
day = datetime.date( f[0], f[1], f[2] )

print day
```

but when I try to write it this way:

```
day = datetime.date( f )
```

I get an exception:  TypeError: an integer is required

Why is that and how could I write this better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best is to use the `datetime.strptime()` method:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = "2012-12-19"                
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
datetime.date(2012, 12, 19)
```

You are not passing `f[0]`, etc. in though, your method would have worked had you done that or:

```
datetime.date(*f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Pack the argument list instead of passing it to `date()` as is:

```
day = datetime.date(*f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, at least this is more readable:

```
day = datetime.date(year=f[0], month=f[1], day=f[2])
```